# Question about Region setting in Redmi note11

Tags: xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

Yesterday I wanted to change the language in my Redmi Note11, but by accident,  I saw `Region` setting set as `United States(system)`.

I want to ask that, I live in Thailand, bought this phone in Thailand and never been to USA. If I leave this “region” setting as USA instead of Thailand, Does it affect to

1. My Security and Privacy
2. My mobile data charge and cost
3. My Wi-Fi Security and Privacy
4. My phone feature

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't affect any of those items. It is for time settings, date format, default keyboard, etc.

I would change it to Thailand, none the less.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information.